# Conduit: How? Multiple Producers to One Consumer with Backpressure

Tags: haskell, conduit

Is there anyway I can express "backpressure" to throttle the production of values from a conduit source?

Suppose I have something similar to:

```
source :: ConduitT () Tweet Twitter ()
source = do
  ts <- lift $ getNewTweets [("screen_name", "Bits90824664")]
  yieldMany ts
  _ <- liftIO $ threadDelay 3000000
  source
```

Where `getNewTweets` requests its data through a throttled web API. I've successfully been able to "pace" the amount of requests being performed by adding a `threadDelay` in the producer. However, I am planning on adding additional sources to my pipeline and start consuming data from each producer in a cyclic manner. So, placing a  `threadDelay` in the producer no longer makes sense. I would like to place the delay somewhere upstream.

I've tried things like adding the delay to the consumer or adding an `iterMC` with a `threadDelay` into the middle of the pipeline but doesn't do anything. I'm guessing multi-threading is occurring so the delays don't work correctly?

Or, a new thought! Most of the time my producer doesn't produce any values at all and does a `yieldMany []`... so having the delay outside the consumer might not be working unless I treat `[]` as a normal stream value and rewrite the producer to be `ConduitT () [Value] IO ()`. <s>Any ideas on if this will work with the chunked (`CE`) variants of consumers or will the empty chunks be short-circuited somehow?</s> I'm thinking I would use a non-chunked transformer to add the delay so that it'll be triggered with each request and will use one of the CE variants of consumers at the end of the pipeline. I will experiment when I get a chance.

If there is some other technique to code this sort of behavior in Haskell I would be thankful for any advice as I'm relatively new to Haskell especially the conduit library; I'm not even sure how/if I can cycle through the multiple sources in the first place.

Comment: Look at `zipSource` for cycling between sources. Conduit is downstream-driven so adding a delay in the consumer should work(?) What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the stream to return chunks of data (including empty chunks) allows the delay to be added upstream. I've got a rough prototype working with ZipSource but will most likely need to change my approach to get the sources to pull data independently of each other.

```
followUser :: Text -> ConduitT () [Tweet] Twitter ()
followUser sn = do
  ts <- lift $ getNewTweets [("screen_name", sn)]
  yield ts
  source

handleTweet :: Tweet -> IO ()
handleTweet = print

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let sources = sequenceSources [ followUser "user1"
                                , followUser "user2"
                                ]

  _ <- runTwitter $ runConduit
    $ sources
    .| iterMC (\a -> threadDelay 3000000)
    .| mapM_CE (liftIO . Prelude.mapM_ handleTweet)

  return ()
```